# How to extract inclusion probabilities from bsts R package

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

The `bsts` R package (Bayesian Structural Time Series) calculates inclusion probabilities for each predictor in a model, which can be plotted via the [`PlotBstsPredictors`](https://github.com/cran/bsts/blob/master/R/plots.R#L261) function. How can I extract these as values for a given `bsts` model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GetInclusionProbabilities <- function(bsts.object) {
  # Pulls code from
  # - BoomSpikeSlab::PlotMarginalInclusionProbabilities
  # - bsts::PlotBstsCoefficients
  burn <- SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.object)
  beta <- bsts.object$coefficients
  beta <- beta[-(1:burn), , drop = FALSE]
  inclusion.prob <- colMeans(beta != 0)
  index <- order(inclusion.prob)
  inclusion.prob <- inclusion.prob[index]
  # End from BoomSpikeSlab/bsts.
  return(data.frame(predictor = names(inclusion.prob),
                    inclusion.prob = inclusion.prob))
}
```

This can also be used with `CausalImpact` by passing `impact$model$bsts.model`.

Comment: How to interpret inclusion probability?

Comment: @Masoud I'd suggest asking that as a separate SO question, perhaps on Cross Validated.